# local orientation preserving/reversing loops

Tags: algebraic-topology

For a nonorientable manifold $M$, there should be a map $\pi_1(M, x_0)\to \mathbb{Z}_2$ indicating whether a loop preserves/reverses local orientation at $x_0$.

What's a good way to obtain/think about it in the context of algebraic topology? I don't know any differential stuff.

Comment: FWIW, if $M$ is differentiable of dimension $d> 0$, then this is the map $\pi_{1}(M)\to \pi_{0}(\text{GL}_{d}(\mathbb{R}))$ in the long exact sequence of the [frame bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_bundle) of $M$. If $M$ is Riemannian, then the analogous statement holds with the orthonormal frame bundle and orthogonal group instead. These facts justify the physical intuition behind orientability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any connected manifold $M$ and point $p\in M$, there is a homomorphism $\omega\colon\pi_1(M,p)\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, the orientation character, that maps a loop to $\pm1$ depending on whether it preserves/reverses orientation. The orientation character is trivial if and only if $M$ is orientable. Here's two related ways of thinking about it:

1. There is a two-fold cover $\tilde{M}\rightarrow M$, the orientation covering, which has $\tilde{M}$ is orientable and is trivial if and only if $M$ is orientable. The orientation character is essentially the first boundary map of the fibration LES associated to this covering
   $$\dotsc\rightarrow\pi_1(\tilde{M},\tilde{p})\rightarrow\pi_1(M,p)\stackrel{\partial}{\rightarrow}\pi_0(F)\rightarrow\pi_0(\tilde{M})\rightarrow\pi_0(M)=1.$$
   This sequence usually only is an exact sequence of pointed sets in the final terms, but we can identify $\pi_0(F)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ by identifying $\tilde{p}$ (a chosen basepoint of $\tilde{M}$ lying over $p$) with $+1$. It still requires an argument that $\omega$ is a homomorphism, but the exact sequence makes it clear that $\omega$ is trivial if and only $\pi_0(F)\rightarrow\pi_0(\tilde{M})$ is surjective if and only if $\pi_0(\tilde{M})$ is disconnected. Thus, the characterizations of orientability in terms of the orientation character and in terms of the orientation covering are equivalent.
2. The homomorphism then factors through a homomorphism $H_1(M,\mathbb{Z})=\pi_1(M,p)^{ab}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ by the Hurewicz theorem. It then factors through a homomorphism $H_1(M,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})=H_1(M,\mathbb{Z})/2H_1(M,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ by the Bockstein exact sequence. This corresponds to an element $w_1\in H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ by the universal coefficient theorem. This cohomology class is a so-called characteristic class, the first Stiefel-Whitney class of $M$. (This also has an interpretation in the differential setting.) In fact, isomorphism classes of two-fold coverings of $M$, isomorphism classes of real line bundles over $M$ and elements of $H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ are each in bijection with one another (and all in bijection with homotopy classes of maps $M\rightarrow\mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$). This correspondence identifies $w_1$ with the orientation covering of $M$. This yields another characterization that orientability is equivalent to the vanishing of $w_1$.